# subprocess.Popen() and --background?

Tags: python, scripting

I have noticed that if blender is launched in background with a python script and arguments via a subprocess, it seems not to work...

For example, with a script to rename a material in a blend file called ren.py :

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
#sub = subprocess.Popen(['blender', '/home/pegasi/green.blend', '--python', '/home/pegasi/change_material_name.py', 'green', 'plip'])
sub = subprocess.Popen(['blender', '--background', '/home/pegasi/green.blend', '--python', '/home/pegasi/change_material_name.py', 'green', 'plip'])
sub.wait()
```

with change_material_name.py :

```
import bpy
import sys
import os
from os.path import join

library_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #target = sys.argv[4]
    #new_name = sys.argv[5]

    target = sys.argv[5]
    new_name = sys.argv[6]

    bpy.data.materials[target].name = new_name
    bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
    bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

when I launch python ren.py, it only output an empty blender.crash.txt while it works like a charm if I remove the --background option.

I am running blender 2.77a and archlinux.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the blender file path be before `--background` argument?

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

sub = subprocess.Popen(['blender', '/home/pegasi/green.blend', '--background', '--python', '/home/pegasi/change_material_name.py', 'green', 'plip'])
sub.wait()
```